# References to equations broken

Tags: errors, equations, cross-referencing

I have written a latex document, and in this document I reference to equations, tables, and figures. Everything works perfectly.

Now I discovered that I have to use a specific template. Therefore I copy-past my latex code into the template .tex file, and now equation reference is broken. References to tables and figures still work, the bibliography is still fine, but any reference to an equation ends up with a (??).

I am not sure what could be causing this, maybe some loaded packages? (I only load hyperref last).

This is the list of packages I load:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,english,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[hang,bottom,stable,multiple]{footmisc} 
\usepackage{appendix} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[sort,round]{natbib} 
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{thmtools} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{datetime} 
%\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{graphicx,listings,xcolor,textcomp}
\usepackage{mcode} 
\usepackage[margin=10pt, font=small, labelfont=bf, labelsep=endash]{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{array,hhline}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

%instructions to make the algorithm pseudo-code package work
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\makeatletter
\def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Please tell me what other informations I should include.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `cleveref` needs to be loaded after `hyperref`

Comment: @samcarter Ah, thank you very much, I completely missed that. It solves the problem. Please make than an answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: @samcarter Well, to be fair it is a duplicate only once you know what was causing the problem. Somebody having the same problem won't google for "packages to load after hyperref" :-)

Comment: That's why your questions is valuable for this site. Somebody having the same problem will google and find your questions and can follow the link to the solution.

Comment: @samcarter Sure. My point was that if you don't understand why reference to equations are not working, you don't expect to find your solution on the page "what packages should be loaded after hyperref". You're missing the key information that your problem is happening because cleveref needs to be loaded after hyperref. My question is a duplicate only when you already know the answer. IMHO it would be better to answer the question, and put a link saying "other packages that should be loaded after hyperref are....". In any case it's fine either way, just wanted to point it out :)